# Extend data frame column with inflation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to extend some code to be able to:
1) read in a vector of prices
2) left join that vector of prices to a data frame of years (or years and months)
3) append/fill the prices for missing years with interpolated data based on the last year of available prices plus a specified inflation rate. Consider an example like this one:

```
prices <- data.frame(year=2018:2022,
                wti=c(75,80,90,NA,NA),
                brent=c(80,85,94,93,NA))
```

What I need is something that will fill the missing rows of each column with the last price plus inflation (suppose 2%). I can do this in a pretty brute force way as:

```
i_rate<-0.02
for(i in c(1:nrow(prices))){
   if(is.na(prices$wti[i]))
     prices$wti[i]<-prices$wti[i-1]*(1+i_rate)
   if(is.na(prices$brent[i]))
     prices$brent[i]<-prices$brent[i-1]*(1+i_rate)
}
```

It seems to me there should be a way to do this using some combination of apply() and/or fill() but I can't seem to make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Kind of an aside, but is there a reason why you're using NA in quotes? Is this an issue you need to work around in your real data?

Comment: No reason. Will fix in the post.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @camille, the problem with `dplyr::lag` is that it doesn't work here with consecutive `NA`s because it uses the "original" `i`th element of a vector instead of the "revised" `i`th element. We'd have to first create a version of `lag` that will do this by creating a new function:

```
impute_inflation <- function(x, rate) {
  output <- x
  y <- rep(NA, length = length(x)) #Creating an empty vector to fill in with the loop. This makes R faster to run for vectors with a large number of elements.

  for (i in seq_len(length(output))) {
    if (i == 1) {
      y[i] <- output[i] #To avoid an error attempting to use the 0th element.
    } else {
      y[i] <- output[i - 1]
    }

    if (is.na(output[i])) {
      output[i] <- y[i] * (1 + rate)
    } else {
      output[i]
    }
  }
  output
}
```

Then it's a pinch to apply this across a bunch of variables with `dplyr::mutate_at()`:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_at(prices, vars(wti, brent), impute_inflation, 0.02)

  year    wti brent
1 2018 75.000 80.00
2 2019 80.000 85.00
3 2020 90.000 94.00
4 2021 91.800 93.00
5 2022 93.636 94.86
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Nice to see my Twitter addiction paying off in SO.  I'll try this out and post again, but one quick question - since in my case, NAs are going to be absorbing (once a series goes to NA, it will stay that way), I think I can just use the second half if your loop, but I'll play with it a bit.

Comment: Works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::lag` to get the previous value in a given column. Your lagged values look like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

inflation_factor <- 1.02

prices <- data_frame(year=2018:2022,
                     wti=c(75,80,90,NA,NA),
                     brent=c(80,85,94,93,NA)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(wti, brent), as.numeric)

prices %>%
  mutate(prev_wti = lag(wti))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>    year   wti brent prev_wti
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  2018    75    80       NA
#> 2  2019    80    85       75
#> 3  2020    90    94       80
#> 4  2021    NA    93       90
#> 5  2022    NA    NA       NA
```

When a value is `NA`, multiply the lagged value by the inflation factor. As you can see, that doesn't handle consecutive `NA`s, however.

```r
prices %>%
  mutate(wti = ifelse(is.na(wti), lag(wti) * inflation_factor, wti),
         brent = ifelse(is.na(brent), lag(brent) * inflation_factor, brent))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    year   wti brent
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2018  75    80  
#> 2  2019  80    85  
#> 3  2020  90    94  
#> 4  2021  91.8  93  
#> 5  2022  NA    94.9
```

Or to scale this and avoid doing the same multiplication over and over, `gather` the data into a long format, get lags *within each group* (wti, brent, or any others you may have), and adjust values as needed. Then you can `spread` back to the original shape:

```r
prices %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, wti, brent) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), lag(value) * inflation_factor, value)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = key, value = value)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    year brent   wti
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2018  80    75  
#> 2  2019  85    80  
#> 3  2020  94    90  
#> 4  2021  93    91.8
#> 5  2022  94.9  NA
```

Created on 2018-07-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! The consecutive NA's really are the core of the issue though - in my actual model, I'll have (potentially) decades of missing values to fill via "last plus inflation".  I probably should have made that more clear in my reproducible example.